# How to set value globally using map in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am using a service like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Client } from '../../inventory/setting/client';

 @Injectable()

 export class UIService {
 public client?: Client;
 public isFullWidth?: boolean = false;
  public data?: boolean;
   constructor() {
        }
  myMap = new Map();



 public setData(key, data) {
   console.log("here");
   this.myMap.set(key, data);
                           }

    public getData(key) {
    return this.myMap.get(key);
  }

  }
```

in my controller i am seting key value using a method

```
     changeView() {
this.toggle = !this.toggle;
this.uiService.setData("category",this.toggle);
console.log(this.uiService.getData("category"));
}

ngOnInit(): void {
console.log("on",this.uiService.getData("category"));
this.getCategories();
}
```

but when i go to other page and com back to this page, what ever i set using setData method is not saved.

the console.log in oninit method always return undefined.

How can i make the key value pair to save globally and should be accessible if i change the page also.

Answer (score 0):

You must create global service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    interface Global{
        [id: string]: any;
    }

@Injectable()
export class GlobalDataService {
    data: Global = {};
}
```

And use it in components

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [LoginService,GlobalDataService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  fValue: NgForm;

  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService, 
    private global: GlobalDataService,
    private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  click(form: NgForm){
          this.loginService.postData(form.value)
                .subscribe(
                  (data) => {
                       this.global.user=data.body.user;
                       console.log(this.global.user);
                      });

  }

}
```